# get all possible keys / key paths in a json string in r

Tags: r

How can I get all the different possible json paths in a json string?  Often I get huge

For example, I would like to get something back like:

```
result = data.frame(paths = c('name',
                                                      'name.first'
                                                      ,'name.last'
                                                      ,'address'
                                                      ,'address.city'
                                                      ,'address.state'
                                                      ,'age'
                                                      ,'income'
                                                      ,'block'))

 result
```

given something like this...

```
myjson='{  

"name": {
"first": "jack",
"last": "smith"
},
"address": {"city": "bigtown", "state": "texas"},
"age": "21",
"income": "123",
"block" :["abc","xyz"]
}'
```

I've tried experimenting with `jsonlite::fromJson` but that doesn't seem to get me to what I'm after exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the full paths:

```
data.frame(result = names(as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(myjson))))

         result
1    name.first
2     name.last
3  address.city
4 address.state
5           age
6        income
7         block
```

If you need all partial paths along with all full paths:

```
data.frame(
  result = sort(unique(
    c(names(fromJSON(myjson)), 
      names(as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(myjson))))))
  )

         result
1       address
2  address.city
3 address.state
4           age
5         block
6        income
7          name
8    name.first
9     name.last
```